# Determining a basis for solution set

Tags: linear-algebra

> For a given equation system (over field $R$), determine the basis for
>   the space $\operatorname{Sol}(U)$ (where $\operatorname{Sol}$ is a set of solutions):
>
> \begin{cases} 2x + 7y + 3z+t=0 \\ 3x + 5y + 2z + 2t=0 \\ 9x + 4y + z+7t=0 \end{cases}

It's a new type of problem for me and I'm struggling a bit. I know what a basis is but am quite confused about the $\operatorname{Sol}(U)$ part. Does that mean I should just try to solve the system and then think of such a basis that it spans over the possible solutions?

Comment: You can use Gaussian elimination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check that the set of solutions to any system of homogeneous linear equations with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$ is indeed a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$.  If there are $n$ variables, the set of solutions will be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$.  As mentioned in the comments, to find a basis of this subspace, use Gaussian elimination.

Without going through all of the steps, the coefficient matrix of the system you've given has reduced row echelon form:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&\frac{-1}{11}&\frac{9}{11}\\0&1&\frac{5}{11}&\frac{-1}{11}\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

The columns that don't have leading $1$'s represent free variables, so $z$ and $t$ are free variables.  The rows represent the equations $11x=z-9t$ and $11y=t-5z$.  The solution set is then:

$$\left\{\begin{pmatrix}11x\\11y\\11z\\11t\\\end{pmatrix}\middle|z,t\in\mathbb{R}\right\}=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}z-9t\\t-5z\\11z\\11t\\\end{pmatrix}\middle|z,t\in\mathbb{R}\right\}=\operatorname{Span}_{\mathbb{R}}\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1\\-5\\11\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}-9\\1\\0\\11\end{pmatrix}\right\}$$

Answer (score 1):

Put the system into an augmented matrix:

$$\left[\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
    2 & 7 & 3 & 1 & 0 \\
    3 & 5 & 2 & 2 & 0 \\
    9 & 4 & 1 & 7 & 0
  \end{array}\right]$$

Use Gauss-Jordan elimination to get it into reduced row echelon form.

$$\left[\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
    1 & 0 & -\frac{1}{11} & \frac{9}{11} & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & \frac{5}{11} & -\frac{1}{11} & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
  \end{array}\right]$$

Now you have a set of equations:

$$\begin{align}
x+0y+-\frac{1}{11}z+\frac{9}{11}t&=0 \\
0x+y+\frac{5}{11}z-\frac{1}{11}t &= 0
\end{align}$$

Finally, parameterize it with $u$ and $v$ as follows:
$$\begin{align}
x&=\space\space\space\frac{1}{11}u-\frac{9}{11}v \\
y&=-\frac{5}{11}u+\frac{1}{11}v \\
z&=u \\
t&=v \end{align}$$

The span of the solution set is therefore:
$$
u\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{11} \\
-\frac{5}{11} \\
1 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}+
v\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{9}{11} \\
\frac{1}{11} \\
0 \\
1
\end{bmatrix}
$$